Whenever I Enter Flutter Doctor on CMD It Crashes
I deleted my previous running Flutter from Document folder and installed a new one on C://flutter. When I tried to run the new Flutter on CMD, it crashes. It instantly crashes whenever I run "flutter doctor".
See screenshot of my environment variables

Can You share the Crash error screen

How do I see the crash error because whenever I type Flutter Doctor on CMD it just close the window without displaying anything.

"flutter --version" working ?

Really? Try creating another cmd session inside the cmd window. (You can nest them arbitrarily; use exit to terminate the current one.)

@sumit Banwakade, I am using flutter_windows_3.22.1-stable

@triplee, it gave me this error when I tried to do a nexted CDM: Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. But when I run git --version it gives me git version 2.45.1.windows.1

"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd" try to remove this from env and run the command again

That seems unrelated to what you were asking.

Move the last line related to flutter to the first line and try it again.
it sometimes work(Select the flutter and use moveUp)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
